# Passing a standard enum value

Tags: c++, qt

I'm coding a toast-style messagebox, but I haven't been able to directly pass the standard icons. The switch below works, but is so clunky. What's the proper way to do this so I can get rid of the switch selection?

```
void MainWindow::mtoast(int msgtime,int level, QString msg)
{
    QMessageBox *mbox = new QMessageBox;
    mbox->setStandardButtons(0);
    mbox->setText(msg);

    switch(level){
        case 0:
            mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::NoIcon);
            break;
        case 1:
            mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
            break;
        case 2:
            mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
            break;
        case 3:
            mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            break;
        case 4:
            mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
            break;
    }


    mbox->setWindowFlags ( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
    mbox->show();
    QTimer::singleShot(msgtime, mbox, SLOT(hide()));

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you could not pass the icons correctly?

Comment: I mean that I haven't been able to pass a value directly to mbox->setIcon.   It wants mbox->setIcon(QMessageBox::<something>);. How can I pass QMessageBox::<something> as an argument?

Comment: @Alan isn't this what exactly my answer shows how to do?

Comment: Yes, it works great. I don't know why it was downvoted. I accepted it as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function signature so that it accepts a reference to [`enum QMessageBox::Icon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#Icon-enum%20%60enum%20QMessageBox::Icon%60) as the second parameter instead of `int level`. Something like this:

```
void MainWindow::mtoast(int msgtime, const enum QMessageBox::Icon& icon, QString msg)
{
    QMessageBox *mbox = new QMessageBox;
    mbox->setStandardButtons(0);
    mbox->setText(msg);
    mbox->setIcon(icon); //this statement replaces the entire switch
    mbox->setWindowFlags ( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
    mbox->show();
    QTimer::singleShot(msgtime, mbox, SLOT(hide()));

}
```

Comment: Side note: there is no advantage in passing `enum` by reference.

Comment: @kefir500 the advantage of passing values by reference is that we're being explicit about what the function accepts - a reference to an instance of the enum itself. If it were passed by value, the caller could pass an arbitrary integer value by casting it to the enum type like `(QMessageBox::Icon(384))` so, without regards to if 384 is a valid value within the enum (which isn't in our case). However, if it were a reference variable, this wouldn't compile and the caller will have to pass a valid reference to an instance of the enum.

Comment: Probably I'm misunderstanding you, but [this example](http://cpp.sh/65ly7) compiles without any errors. Could you also provide an example?

Comment: @kefir500 You were correct all the way. I was wrong, and have been so for years now with all those parameters of reference to enums I've written. Turns out I was doing it that way only with a perceived benefit. :-)